# WordPress shortcode in HTML output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm just wondering is it possible to output a wordpress shortcode inside html output in my javascript page?

You see I have a javascript file and inside it is below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bannav li a").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var hrefval = $(this).attr("href");
        if (hrefval == "#enquire") {
          var distance = $('#banner').css('right');
          $('.banner-rt-content1').html('
            <div style="padding:20px;">
            [contact-form-7 id="102" title="Make an Enquiry"]
            </div>
          ');
          if (distance == "auto" || distance == "0px") {
            $(this).addClass("open");
            openSidepage();
          }
        }
```

The thing is I want to output my *Contact Form 7* form within this JS page using their WordPress shortcode `[contact-form-7 id="102" title="Make an Enquiry"]`. Is that even possible?

Comment: off the top of my head you could do <?php do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="102" title="Make an Enquiry"]') ?> in your js but that might be a bit messy

Comment: no, you cant do that. You could have the above javascript in a file with .php extension, and use the wordpress php function do_shortcode();

Comment: Alternatly add the shortcode into your page template somewhere so it is executed on page load, hide it with css and then show / move it in your js

Answer (score 0):

Shortcodes in Wordpress are processed in PHP before the page loads. Unfortunately there isn't a super easy way to process them directly in your javascript. You need to either make an AJAX handler to get the output of the processed shortcode, or have PHP write the javascript for you. AJAX in Wordpress is slightly more difficult than the second option so I will explain that one instead.

You can localize the output of your shortcode and then reference it in your javascript. Since most wordpress themes use jQuery I will localize the script to that. Add this to your functions file:

```
$translation = do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="102" title="Make an Enquiry"]');

wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'contact_form', array( 'html' => $translation) );
```

Then in your javascript do this:

```
$('.banner-rt-content1').html('<div style="padding:20px;">'+contact_form.html+'</div>');
```

That should get the content you need into the page.